# Logistic regressioin - contradictory results?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am using the glmer method in lme4 to build a mixed effect logistic regression model, the model is as follows:

```
 textbook.usage.glm <- glmer(textbook.usageSession ~ session.week * condition.player  + (session.week|group.name),family="binomial",data=dfAN)
```

When I run the summary

```
  summary(textbook.usage.glm)
```

I got the following results:

```
      Generalized linear mixed model fit by the Laplace approximation 
      Formula: textbook.usageSession ~ session.week * condition.player + (session.week |      group.name) 
      Data: dfAN 
      AIC   BIC logLik deviance
      104.9 123.1 -45.45     90.9
      Random effects:
      Groups     Name         Variance Std.Dev. Corr   
      group.name (Intercept)  0.45445  0.67413         
        session.week 0.17793  0.42181  -0.484 
      Number of obs: 99, groups: group.name, 6

     Fixed effects:
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
     (Intercept)                            4.6851     3.4607   1.354   0.1758  
     session.week                          -1.2304     0.8017  -1.535   0.1248  
     condition.playerDEFAULT                4.7845     4.2266   1.132   0.2576  
     session.week:condition.playerDEFAULT  -3.1617     1.4026  -2.254   0.0242 *
     ---
     Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) sssn.w c.DEFA
    session.wek -0.976              
    cnd.DEFAULT -0.787  0.765       
    s.:.DEFAULT  0.515 -0.506 -0.926
```

From the above statistics, we can see only one significance for the interaction between session.week and condition.player. But there is no significance on the main effect (condition.player) alone. However, if we further build three incremental models as follows, and run anova to test the significance of each variable

```
    textbook.usage.glm.2 <- glmer(textbook.usageSession ~ session.week +  condition.player + (session.week|group.name),family="binomial",data=dfAN)
    textbook.usage.glm.1 <- glmer(textbook.usageSession ~ session.week + (session.week|group.name),family="binomial",data=dfAN)
    textbook.usage.glm.0 <- glmer(textbook.usageSession ~ 1 + (session.week|group.name),family="binomial",data=dfAN)
   anova(textbook.usage.glm.0,textbook.usage.glm.1,textbook.usage.glm.2,textbook.usage.glm)
```

We get

```
  Data: dfAN
  Models:
  textbook.usage.glm.0: textbook.usageSession ~ 1 + (session.week | group.name)
  textbook.usage.glm.1: textbook.usageSession ~ session.week + (session.week | group.name)
  textbook.usage.glm.2: textbook.usageSession ~ session.week + condition.player + (session.week | 
  textbook.usage.glm.2:     group.name)
  textbook.usage.glm: textbook.usageSession ~ session.week * condition.player + (session.week | 
  textbook.usage.glm:     group.name)
                 Df    AIC    BIC  logLik   Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
  textbook.usage.glm.0  4 126.57 136.95 -59.284                              
  textbook.usage.glm.1  5 125.43 138.41 -57.716  3.1376      1    0.07651 .  
  textbook.usage.glm.2  6 109.48 125.05 -48.738 17.9548      1  2.262e-05 ***
  textbook.usage.glm    7 104.91 123.07 -45.452  6.5716      1    0.01036 *  
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Here, we see, by adding condition.player in the model 2, it is significant as well, in addition to significance to the interaction effect.

How can I report the result? Is the condition.player variable significant or not? I've seen many logistic regression examples with the first approach, what is the difference between that and the second approach where I compare models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are testing different things for different purposes.

The first result is doing the Wald test for each variable (term).
So the main effects are themselves not significant, while the interaction is significant.
But for the hierarchy rule, the main effects should be included in this textbook.usage.glm

The second result is doing the Chi square test, for comparing different models (glm.1, glm.2, glm) to textbook.usage.glm.0
We can see that glm.2, glm.3 are significantly different from the glm.0 (glm.1 depending on the significance level we choose). Note that the Chi square test can not do multi-comparison.
But from the AIC and BIC, we can see that final glm is the best one among these candidate models (glm.0,1,2 and glm).

Note: this is not a formal step by step forward selection unless we also try textbook.usageSession ~ condition.player. Maybe this model is more significant than the glm.1

Comment: thanks. I have questions regarding your answers. 1. What do you mean by "for the hierarchy rule, the main effects should be included in this textbook.usage.glm". 2. Is there a way to visualize the main effects and the interaction effects? 3.  what do you mean by "not a formal step by step forward selection"? Do you mean if I I do textbook.usageSession~condition.player for textbook.usage.glm.1, I would get different results?  4. glmer function with binomial family gives p-values directly, but lmer for linear regression it does not give p-values, how do you usually compute significance?

Comment: @nan 1.Because the interaction is significant, the main effect should be included. But I just mean that textbook.usage.glm itself rather than model selection. We seldom drop variables simply by Wald test. 2.Visualization is seldom used for multivariate models. But you can try to plot textbook.usageSession~condition.player, with different values of session.week. This plot of final glm will be several lines with different slopes and intercepts. However, the other pair plot textbook.usageSession~session.week is supposed be more in a mess because of the random effect (you may have a look).

Comment: @nan 3. The forward selection in lmer usually find the find the fixed effect first, including interaction. Then try to test whether random effect should be included or not. 4. summary of the lmer seems still the Wald test. So we can still compare the z value with the Normal distribution.